# Nearest Neigborood using a confidence region

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, knn, nearest-neighbor, semisupervised-learning

I have more than 1M data points and 32 of them (Orange in the pic) are my true class.
I would like to find similar blue points to the orange ones.
Feature vectors are just embeddings.
[image]
The approach that I took is to build a *pseudo 95 confidence region* and then flag the points within that area as my true label.
I think I cannot use a KNN algorithm for the following reasons:

- I only know beforehand what points belong to the positive class.
- KNN would be highly overfitted as I only have 32 positive data points over more than 1M dat points.
  Is there any other algorithm or approach that suits better this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Clustering very large data sets tend to grind to a halt. Here's a crazy idea. Can you take a random sample of the data set and work with that? If the selection process is totally random, it's just a subset of your full data set, and the smaller piece should be very representative of the full thing. It should be as simple as this.

```
subset = df.sample(frac=0.5)
```

See this link for more info.

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-sample-a-dataframe-in-python-pandas-d18a3187139b

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not sure if I well understood well. I already sampled the dataset from a 50M points dataset. Any suggestion about the approach? Not sure if it is indeed a real clustering because I already know beforehand I have 32 labelled points.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a clustering experiment. Clustering is unsupervised because you don't know what the outcome will be.